# htaccess: route all domains to their respective subfolders

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've configured my server so all domains are routed to the same folder on my server (htdocs). Within that folder I created seperate folders for each domain, like so:

```
htdocs/
htdocs/domain1.com/
htdocs/domain2.com/
htdocs/domain3.com/
```

I'd like to route the domains with .htaccess so that if domain1.com is requested, the contents of the folder "domain1.com" is shown (etc.). After a lot of trial and error I've been able to produce the following code, which works great for what I'm trying to achieve:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+\.(com|nl|net))$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

The only downside to the above code is that if someone requests: http://domain1.com/domain2.com, the contents of htdocs/domain2.com is shown :-( Is there a way I can prevent this? What am I missing here?

Comment: deny direct access to the domain directories: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/[^./]+\.(?:com|nl|net)/` \n `RewriteRule ^ - [F]`

Comment: +1 for coming up with a simple different approach. I would still prefer http://domain1.com/domain2.com/ to return not found, but I guess I could always force a 404 using your approach.

Comment: `R=404` should work. Note, `%{REQUEST_URI}` contains a front slash.

Comment: Thanks, that works like a charm!